# mysql bash_profile password to be ignored

Tags: unix

I was looking for unix bash history to give *** for mysql password.
Eg: If I issue -
mysql -uroot -psecuritydemon -h192.168.90.888

then in unix prompt if I use history | grep -i mysql -> I get the password entry too.. Instead I would like to see for the history grep result as below

mysql -uroot -p***** -h192.168.90.888

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to filter the command that is written to your history in bash. However, I would suggest you use a `~/.my.cnf` configuration file as described here: http://support.modwest.com/content/6/242/en/how-do-i-create-a-mycnf-mysql-preference-file.html
. And make sure you set the permissions to `go-rwx` so that noone else can read your file.

Answer (score 0):

Your bash history is not the biggest (or at least not the only) concern: if you run sql this way, anyone can see your password with a simple `ps ax` while your session is open! Instead use `mysql -uroot -p` without a password: then the mysql client will present a password prompt that nobody can sniff (unless they're standing over your shoulder, or have root on your computer, or something equally unpreventable).